# Nesting routes in Angular UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

(AngularJS v1.2.0-rc.3 + Angular UI-Router v0.2.0)

In my `index.html`, I have the following code:

```
<div class="container" ui-view></div>
```

In my app.js, I have the following code:

```
    $stateProvider
    .state('projects', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/projects',
        template: '<ui-view />',
    })
    // below display properly
    .state('projects.list', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'views/project_list.html',
        controller: 'ProjectListCtrl'
    })
    // below display properly
    .state('projects.one', {
        url: '/{projectId:[0-9]{1,8}}',
        templateUrl: 'views/project_dashboard.html',
        controller: 'ProjectCtrl'
    })
    // below does not display at all
    .state('projects.one.campaigns', {
        url: '/campaigns',
        template: 'I cannot seem to display this text'
    })
```

I can hit the following routes just fine: `index.html/projects`, `index.html/projects/1`, but I cannot hit this route: `index.html/projects/1/campaigns`

Does anyone know why I can't?

Bonus points if you can answer how I could display the `projects.one.campaigns` state on the same URL page as the `projects.one` state.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is because `projects.one` matches before `projects.one.campaigns`

Add a `projects.one` abstract state and then add a `projects.one.default` state with the templateUrl.

```
.state('projects.one', {
    url: '/{projectId:[0-9]{1,8}}',
    abstract:true,
    template: '<ui-view/>',
})
.state('projects.one.default', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: 'views/project_dashboard.html',
    controller: 'ProjectCtrl'
})
.state('projects.one.campaigns', {
    url: '/campaigns',
    template: 'I cannot seem to display this text'
}
```

To display the template of the campaigns on the same page of the projects.one you should not use a state but a directive instead and toggle with ng-show on the same page.

Comment: You got it. (One quick type note: the url for 'projects.one.default' should be an empty string because it inherits the url from projects.one

Comment: "The reason is because `projects.one` matches before `projects.one.campaigns`". What does that mean?

Comment: @JosephSilber when the ui.router receives a state transition request with some name it will iterate through the state list's url and return the first url that begins (or if it has variables, it will 'match' in terms of regular expressions) with the requested url.

Comment: @fabrizioM - I'm still puzzled. Are you saying that in addition to responding to a `/projects/:id` url, the `projects.one` state also responds to `/projects/:id/*`?

Comment: 2014 today, you saved my day(infact night wasted whole day doing this)

Answer (score 1):

I just spent whole day dealing with this problem.

I found out, that you don't need abstract states at all!

Try this:
index.html:

```
<div class="container"><ui-view/></div>
```

use directive ui-view as a tag in the top level template.

Now all your nested templates wrap like this:

```
<ui-view>
    <div>
        template code
    </div>
</ui-view>
```

and now you can just:

```
   $stateProvider        
    .state('list', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'views/project_list.html',
        controller: 'ProjectListCtrl'
    })
    // below display properly
    .state('one', {
        url: '/{projectId:[0-9]{1,8}}',
        templateUrl: 'views/project_dashboard.html',
        controller: 'ProjectCtrl'
    })
    // below does not display at all
    .state('one.campaigns', {
        url: '/campaigns',
        template: 'I cannot seem to display this text'
    })
```

I needed general solution for the nesting and this works. Now you can create very deep nesting easily (for example *one.campaing.group.member.note*). If you will use ui-view on the top level and wrap all templates with the ui-view, they contact of each template will replace content of the top level ui-view (which is empty).